# Null reference exception when getting an item template in Sitecore

Tags: templates, sitecore

I am getting an exception in the following code line

```
item.Template.ID.ToString();
```

when getting an item from Sitecore, but the template returns `null` and I don't understand why. In sitecore, item is there and its template is also there.

Comment: Maybe you have published the item, but not the template?

Comment: Yeah ,My bad. I got it. Thanks for reply. Its publishing issue.